# Qt application for mac not being launched

Tags: macos, download, launch, macos-mojave

I am working on an application written in Qt for macOS environment. In order to generate release build i have set up external server.

I am seeing this:

After generating build, if I download and install the application on Applications folder, when opening it, first I see the popup asking if I am sure to open app downloaded from Internet(Gatekeeper), so I click Open and then app dies.

App works fine if I open it from CommandLine in Terminal.

Checking the attributes of app file I can see that it has com.apple.quarantine. If remove it manually, using xattr -dr com.apple.quarantine application opens without any problem

Any ideas about why it is not launched ??
Thanks is advance

Comment: Macos version?  Ran macdeployqt?

Comment: MacOS 10.14 Mojave. macqtdeploy was run and it ended without errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem with my software and raised a developer incident which allowed to find the root cause:

When launched the first time with the quarantine attribute, Gatekeeper will pass an additional command-line argument.
From what I could observe, it is of the form:

```
-psn_0_<some sequence of numbers>
```

e.g.

```
-psn_0_2445909
```

Qt's `QCommandLineParser` rejects unknown arguments and calls `exit(1);` in that case.

Thus it is necessary to filter `argc` / `argv` and remove that bogus argument before passing them to `Q{Core,Gui,}Application`.